# How to use modx getResources to return the parent resource one time only?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, getresource

How can I use getResources to get the parent resource from several nodes in a resource tree ~only once~ i.e. I have a getResources call:

```
[[!getResources?  
    &parents=`738,746,1222, 748, 1216, 805, 806, 807, 3401`
    &tpl=`SecondaryUpdatesHomePageTpl`  
    &limit=`3`  
    &includeTVs=`1`
    &processTVs=`1`  
    &hideContainers=`1`  
    &includeContent=`0`   
    &depth=`1`  
    &sortby=`{"createdon":"desc"}`
]]
```

Where the &parents ids are the trees to be searched, there may be several new resources in each parent. I need get resources to return the parent resource of the &parents items 'but only once'

For example if parents 738, 748. 807 & 3401 each have 4 or 5 new resources under them, I don't want 738 getting returned 3 times, I need ~the parents of~ 738, 748 & 807 returned.

Any thoughts on how to do this?
[modx revolution 2.2.12]

Comment: Hard to understand without screenshot of your resource tree.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this for a while i guess you basically just have to do another getResources call with the &resources param set to a modified output of the first getResources call. Note that i removed the includeTVs from the nested getResources call.

Change the TPL in your getResources to output the parent followed by a comma, (`[[+parent]],`) basically generating a comma separated list of ID's. Feed the output of your getResources call into another one that has the correct TPL (SecondaryUpdatesHomePageTpl)

```
[[!getResources? 
  &resources=`[[!getResources?  
    &parents=`738,746,1222, 748, 1216, 805, 806, 807, 3401`
    &tpl=`CSVListOfParentsTPL`  
    &limit=`3`  
    &hideContainers=`1`  
    &depth=`1`  
    &sortby=`{"createdon":"desc"}`
  ]]` 
  &tpl=`SecondaryUpdatesHomePageTpl`
  &includeTVs=`1`
  &processTVs=`1`  
]]
```

Nesting like this is clearly not the most efficient solution, the alternative would be writing your own custom snippet that makes a $modx->query out of more or less the same parameters your giving the getResources, but fetching the parents directly instead of doing a second trip to get them.

Comment: Looks like that will still return the same parent multiple times.  I'm going to have to use runSnippet on getresources and then filter the results myself. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the new snippet:

```
[[unikids? &input=`1,5,6` $depth=`5`]]
```

and snipet code:

```
<?php

$array_big = array();
$inputids = explode(",",$input);
foreach($inputids as $inputid) {

 $array_ids = $modx->getChildIds($inputid,$depth,array('context' => 'web'));

        /// add to master array
        $array_big = array_merge ($array_big, $array_ids);
   } 

   $output = implode(",",array_unique($array_big));

 return $output;

?>
```

this snipet outputs unique ids to your getResources parametr :

```
[[!getResources? 
  &resources=`[[unikids? &input=`1,5,6` $depth=`5`]]` 
  &tpl=`SecondaryUpdatesHomePageTpl`
  &includeTVs=`1`
  &processTVs=`1`  
]]
```